# How to prepare project compilation to Azure for MS Teams with "tab" extension and "message-extension"?

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure, botframework, microsoft-teams

Since the project is running locally, it is likely that the reason why the bot is not responding in message-extension is due to bad project configuration for deploy Azure app. I'm not sure how to properly compile the project to the dev version. Every time I fire up the project in dev version on Azure, it gives me an error that "Unable to connect to the application. Try again." - The internal error in the header trace is : "

1. errorCode: 1008
2. message: "<BotError>Agent returned unsuccessful status code InternalServerError"

My project structure is as follows:

```
|-- .vscode/
|-- appPackage/
|-- env/
|-- infra/
|--public/
|-- bot/           <!--message extension source code-->
|   |-- api/
|   |-- index.ts
|   |-- config.ts
|   |-- teamsBot.ts
|   |-- package.json
|   |-- tsconfig.json
|   |-- web.config
|   |-- .webappignore
|-- tab/            <!--your current source code-->
    |-- src/            <!--your current source code-->
    |-- app.jsx
    |-- static/
    |-- views/
|-- package.json
|-- tsconfig.json
|-- teamsapp.local.yml
|-- teamsapp.yml
```

teamsapp.yml configuration:

```
version: v1.2

additionalMetadata:
  sampleTag: msg-ext-with-tab

environmentFolderPath: ./env

provision:
  - uses: teamsApp/create
    with:
      name: MS_TEAMS_TAB_MSGEXT_dev
    writeToEnvironmentFile:
      teamsAppId: TEAMS_APP_ID
  - uses: aadApp/create
    with:
      name: 'MS_TEAMS_TAB_MSGEXT_dev'
      generateClientSecret: true
      signInAudience: 'AzureADMyOrg'
    writeToEnvironmentFile:
      clientId: AAD_APP_CLIENT_ID
      clientSecret: SECRET_AAD_APP_CLIENT_SECRET
      objectId: AAD_APP_OBJECT_ID
      tenantId: AAD_APP_TENANT_ID
      authority: AAD_APP_OAUTH_AUTHORITY
      authorityHost: AAD_APP_OAUTH_AUTHORITY_HOST
  - uses: aadApp/update
    with:
      manifestPath: './aad.manifest.json'
      outputFilePath: ./build/aad.manifest.${{TEAMSFX_ENV}}.json
  - uses: botAadApp/create
    with:
      name: BOT-${{TEAMSFX_ENV}}
    writeToEnvironmentFile:
      botId: BOT_ID
      botPassword: SECRET_BOT_PASSWORD
  - uses: arm/deploy
    with:
      subscriptionId: ${{AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID}}
      resourceGroupName: ${{AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME}}
      templates:
        - path: ./infra/azure.bicep
          parameters: ./infra/azure.parameters.json
          deploymentName: Create-resources-for-tab
      bicepCliVersion: v0.9.1
  - uses: teamsApp/validateManifest
    with:
      manifestPath: ./appPackage/manifest.json
  - uses: teamsApp/zipAppPackage
    with:
      manifestPath: ./appPackage/manifest.json
      outputZipPath: ./appPackage/build/appPackage.${{TEAMSFX_ENV}}.zip
      outputJsonPath: ./appPackage/build/manifest.${{TEAMSFX_ENV}}.json
  - uses: teamsApp/validateAppPackage
    with:
      appPackagePath: ./appPackage/build/appPackage.${{TEAMSFX_ENV}}.zip
  - uses: teamsApp/update
    with:
      appPackagePath: ./appPackage/build/appPackage.${{TEAMSFX_ENV}}.zip
  - uses: azureStorage/enableStaticWebsite
    with:
      storageResourceId: ${{TAB_AZURE_STORAGE_RESOURCE_ID}}
      indexPage: index.html
      errorPage: error.html
deploy:
  - uses: cli/runNpmCommand
    name: install dependencies
    with:
      args: install
  - uses: cli/runNpmCommand
    name: build app
    with:
      args: run build
  - uses: azureStorage/deploy
    with:
      workingDirectory: tab
      artifactFolder: build
      resourceId: ${{TAB_AZURE_STORAGE_RESOURCE_ID}}
  - uses: azureAppService/zipDeploy
    with:
      workingDirectory: bot
      artifactFolder: .
      ignoreFile: .webappignore
      resourceId: ${{BOT_AZURE_APP_SERVICE_RESOURCE_ID}}
publish:
  - uses: teamsApp/validateManifest
    with:
      manifestPath: ./appPackage/manifest.json
  - uses: teamsApp/zipAppPackage
    with:
      manifestPath: ./appPackage/manifest.json
      outputZipPath: ./appPackage/build/appPackage.${{TEAMSFX_ENV}}.zip
      outputJsonPath: ./appPackage/build/manifest.${{TEAMSFX_ENV}}.json
  - uses: teamsApp/validateAppPackage
    with:
      appPackagePath: ./appPackage/build/appPackage.${{TEAMSFX_ENV}}.zip
  - uses: teamsApp/update
    with:
      appPackagePath: ./appPackage/build/appPackage.${{TEAMSFX_ENV}}.zip
  - uses: teamsApp/publishAppPackage
    with:
      appPackagePath: ./appPackage/build/appPackage.${{TEAMSFX_ENV}}.zip
    writeToEnvironmentFile:
      publishedAppId: TEAMS_APP_PUBLISHED_APP_ID
projectId: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

tsconfig.json file in bot folder:

```
{
   "compilerOptions":{
      "incremental":true,
      "tsBuildInfoFile":"./lib/.tsbuildinfo",
      "target":"ES2019",
      "module":"ESNext",
      "rootDir":"./",
      "moduleResolution":"Node",
      "resolveJsonModule":true,
      "declaration":true,
      "sourceMap":true,
      "allowJs":true,
      "outDir":"./lib",
      "esModuleInterop":true,
      "noImplicitAny":false,
      "skipLibCheck":true
   },
   "ts-node":{
      "compilerOptions":{
         "module":"commonjs"
      }
   }
}
```

package.json for bot:

```
{
    "name": "---------",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "msteams": {
        "teamsAppId": null
    },
    "description": "Microsoft Teams Toolkit hello world Bot sample",
    "engines": {
        "node": "16 || 18"
    },
    "author": "Microsoft",
    "license": "MIT",
    "main": "./lib/index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "dev:teamsfx": "env-cmd --silent -f .localConfigs npm run dev",
        "dev": "nodemon --exec node --inspect=9239 --signal SIGINT -r ts-node/register ./index.ts",
        "build": "tsc && shx cp -r ./adaptiveCards ./lib/ && shx cp -r ./api ./lib/",
        "start": "node ./lib/index.js",
        "watch": "nodemon --exec \"npm run start\"",
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@microsoft/adaptivecards-tools": "^1.0.0",
        "@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client": "^3.0.7",
        "@microsoft/teams-js": "^2.17.0",
        "adaptive-expressions": "^4.20.0",
        "adaptivecards": "2.11.1",
        "adaptivecards-templating": "^2.3.1",
        "botbuilder": "^4.20.0",
        "botbuilder-teams": "^0.2.9",
        "node-localstorage": "^3.0.5",
        "restify": "^10.0.0",
        "storage": "^0.2.0",
        "swiper": "^11.0.5"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/node": "^16.18.79",
        "@types/restify": "^8.5.10",
        "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
        "shx": "^0.3.4",
        "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
        "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
        "typescript": "^5.3.3"
    }
}
```

Code fragment for index.ts

```
// Import required packages
import * as restify from 'restify'

// Import required bot services.
// See https://aka.ms/bot-services to learn more about the different parts of a bot.
import {
    CloudAdapter,
    ConfigurationServiceClientCredentialFactory,
    ConfigurationBotFrameworkAuthentication,
    TurnContext,
} from 'botbuilder'

// This bot's main dialog.
import { TeamsBot } from './teamsBot'
import config from './config'

// Create adapter.
// See https://aka.ms/about-bot-adapter to learn more about adapters.
const credentialsFactory = new ConfigurationServiceClientCredentialFactory({
    MicrosoftAppId: config.botId,
    MicrosoftAppPassword: config.botPassword,
    MicrosoftAppType: 'MultiTenant',
})

const botFrameworkAuthentication = new ConfigurationBotFrameworkAuthentication({}, credentialsFactory)

const adapter = new CloudAdapter(botFrameworkAuthentication) 

// Catch-all for errors.
const onTurnErrorHandler = async (context: TurnContext, error: Error) => {
    // This check writes out errors to console log .vs. app insights.
    // NOTE: In production environment, you should consider logging this to Azure
    //       application insights.
    console.error(`\n [onTurnError] unhandled error: ${error}`)

    // Send a trace activity, which will be displayed in Bot Framework Emulator
    await context.sendTraceActivity(
        'OnTurnError Trace',
        `${error}`,
        'https://www.botframework.com/schemas/error',
        'TurnError'
    )

    // Send a message to the user
    await context.sendActivity(`The bot encountered unhandled error:\n ${error.message}`)
    await context.sendActivity('To continue to run this bot, please fix the bot source code.')
}

// Set the onTurnError for the singleton CloudAdapter
adapter.onTurnError = onTurnErrorHandler


// Create the bot that will handle incoming messages.
const bot = new TeamsBot()

// Create HTTP server.
const server = restify.createServer()
server.use(restify.plugins.bodyParser())
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, () => {
    console.log(`\nBot Started, ${server.name} listening to ${server.url}`)
})

// Listen for incoming requests.
server.post('/api/messages', async (req, res, next) => {
    await adapter.process(req, res, async context => {
    try {
      await bot.run(context)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error processing activity:', error);
    }
    })
})
```

Code fragment for TeamsBot.ts

```
import PostIssues from './api/glanceApi/postIssues.js'
import GetGroupsServices from './api/glanceApi/GetGroupsServices.js'
import GetQueueMain from './api/glanceApi/getQueue.js'
import {
    TeamsActivityHandler,
    CardFactory,
    TurnContext,
    AdaptiveCardInvokeValue,
    AdaptiveCardInvokeResponse,
    MessagingExtensionAction,
    MessagingExtensionResponse,
} from 'botbuilder'
import rawWelcomeCard from './adaptiveCards/welcome.json'
import rawLearnCard from './adaptiveCards/learn.json' 
import * as cardTools from '@microsoft/adaptivecards-tools'
import * as ACData from 'adaptivecards-templating'
import * as AdaptiveCards from 'adaptivecards' 

export interface DataInterface {
    likeCount: number
} 

export class TeamsBot extends TeamsActivityHandler { 
    likeCountObj: { likeCount: number }

    constructor() { 
        super()  

        // record the likeCount
        this.likeCountObj = { likeCount: 0 } 

        this.onMessage(async (context, next) => {
            console.log('Running with Message Activity.')
            let txt = context.activity.text
            const removedMentionText = TurnContext.removeRecipientMention(context.activity)
            if (removedMentionText) {
                // Remove the line break
                txt = removedMentionText.toLowerCase().replace(/\n|\r/g, '').trim()
            }

            // Trigger command by IM text
            switch (txt) {
                case 'welcome': {
                    const card = cardTools.AdaptiveCards.declareWithoutData(rawWelcomeCard).render()
                    await context.sendActivity({ attachments: [CardFactory.adaptiveCard(card)] })
                    break 
                }
                case 'learn': {
                    this.likeCountObj.likeCount = 0
                    const card = cardTools.AdaptiveCards.declare(rawLearnCard).render(this.likeCountObj)
                    await context.sendActivity({ attachments: [CardFactory.adaptiveCard(card)] })
                    break
                }
            }

            // By calling next() you ensure that the next BotHandler is run.
            await next()
        })

        // Listen to MembersAdded event, view https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-notifications for more events
        this.onMembersAdded(async (context, next) => {
            const membersAdded = context.activity.membersAdded
            for (let cnt = 0; cnt < membersAdded.length; cnt++) {
                if (membersAdded[cnt].id) {
                    const card = cardTools.AdaptiveCards.declareWithoutData(rawWelcomeCard).render()
                    await context.sendActivity({ attachments: [CardFactory.adaptiveCard(card)] })
                    break
                }
            }
            await next()
        })
    }

    // Invoked when an action is taken on an Adaptive Card. The Adaptive Card sends an event to the Bot and this
    // method handles that event.
    async onAdaptiveCardInvoke(
        context: TurnContext,
        invokeValue: AdaptiveCardInvokeValue
    ): Promise<AdaptiveCardInvokeResponse> {
        // The verb "userlike" is sent from the Adaptive Card defined in adaptiveCards/learn.json
        if (invokeValue.action.verb === 'userlike') {
            this.likeCountObj.likeCount++
            const card = cardTools.AdaptiveCards.declare(rawLearnCard).render(this.likeCountObj)
            await context.updateActivity({
                type: 'message',
                id: context.activity.replyToId,
                attachments: [CardFactory.adaptiveCard(card)],
            })
            return { statusCode: 200, type: undefined, value: undefined }
        }
    }

    // Message extension Code
    // Action.
    public async handleTeamsMessagingExtensionSubmitAction(context: TurnContext, action: any): Promise<any> {
        [HIDDEN CODE]
    }

    // Search.
    async handleTeamsMessagingExtensionQuery(context: TurnContext, query: any): Promise<any> {
        [HIDDEN CODE]
    }

    async GetAdaptiveCard() {
        [HIDDEN CODE]
    }

    public async handleTeamsMessagingExtensionSelectItem(
        context: TurnContext,
        obj: any
    ): Promise<MessagingExtensionResponse> {
        return {
            composeExtension: {
                type: 'result',
                attachmentLayout: 'list',
                attachments: [CardFactory.heroCard(obj.name, obj.description)],
            },
        }
    }

    // Link Unfurling.
    public async handleTeamsAppBasedLinkQuery(context: TurnContext, query: any): Promise<any> {
        const attachment = CardFactory.thumbnailCard('Thumbnail Card', query.url, [query.url])

        // By default the link unfurling result is cached in Teams for 30 minutes.
        // The code has set a cache policy and removed the cache for the app. Learn more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/link-unfurling?tabs=dotnet%2Cadvantages#remove-link-unfurling-cache
        const result = {
            attachmentLayout: 'list',
            type: 'result',
            attachments: [attachment],
            suggestedActions: {
                actions: [
                    {
                        type: 'setCachePolicy',
                        value: '{"type":"no-cache"}',
                    },
                ],
            },
        }
        const response = {
            composeExtension: result,
        }
        return response
    }
}

async function createCardCommand(
    context: TurnContext,
    action: MessagingExtensionAction
): Promise<MessagingExtensionResponse> {
    // The user has chosen to create a card by choosing the 'Create Card' context menu command.
    const data = action.data
    const heroCard = CardFactory.heroCard(data.title, data.text)
    heroCard.content.subtitle = data.subTitle
    const attachment = {
        contentType: heroCard.contentType,
        content: heroCard.content,
        preview: heroCard,
    }

    return {
        composeExtension: {
            type: 'result',
            attachmentLayout: 'list',
            attachments: [attachment],
        },
    }
}

async function createTaskCommand(context, action) {
    [HIDDEN CODE]
}

function shareMessageCommand(context, action) {
    // The user has chosen to share a message by choosing the 'Share Message' context menu command.
    let userName = 'unknown'
    if (
        action.messagePayload &&
        action.messagePayload.from &&
        action.messagePayload.from.user &&
        action.messagePayload.from.user.displayName
    ) {
        userName = action.messagePayload.from.user.displayName
    }

    // This Message Extension example allows the user to check a box to include an image with the
    // shared message.  This demonstrates sending custom parameters along with the message payload.
    let images = []
    const includeImage = action.data.includeImage
    if (includeImage === 'true') {
        images = [
            'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQtB3AwMUeNoq4gUBGe6Ocj8kyh3bXa9ZbV7u1fVKQoyKFHdkqU',
        ]
    }
    const heroCard = CardFactory.heroCard(
        `${userName} originally sent this message:`,
        action.messagePayload.body.content,
        images
    )

    if (action.messagePayload && action.messagePayload.attachments && action.messagePayload.attachments.length > 0) {
        // This sample does not add the MessagePayload Attachments.  This is left as an
        // exercise for the user.
        heroCard.content.subtitle = `(${action.messagePayload.attachments.length} Attachments not included)`
    }

    const attachment = {
        contentType: heroCard.contentType,
        content: heroCard.content,
        preview: heroCard,
    }

    return {
        composeExtension: {
            type: 'result',
            attachmentLayout: 'list',
            attachments: [attachment],
        },
    }
}

export default TeamsBot
```

this is example imported file (postIssue.js):

```
import SetTokenBot from '../token/tokenBot.js'
import { LocalStorage } from 'node-localstorage'

const FlaskTenantsUrl = 'https://demo.XXXX:0000/api/.....'

export async function PostIssues(formData, idUserTeams, actualStateData) {
    if (typeof localStorage === 'undefined' || localStorage === null) {
        global.localStorage = new LocalStorage('./scratch')
    }

    [HIDDEN CODE]
}
export default PostIssues
```

It works the project only for the frontend that is, for "Tab" the files are configured correctly and after running deploy on Azure, you can see the expected results.

For the bot, TypeScript is compiled project to the /lib folder, but I have included to the project "bot" api folder, which is written in JavaScript ES6. The api is written for its own purposes of downloading data from an external private provider. Api files are imported into the teamsBot.ts file.

As I pointed out, locally the project works without errors, the bot responds, but in the dev version the bot does not respond and returns an error.

I have no idea how to configure this so that there are no errors on the Azure side, somewhere in the logs on Azure I came across errors like the following:

`SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`  - this applied either for "restify" or after configuration changes, for "js" files imported into teamsBot....

Since I'm a beginner with this, I ask for your understanding, because the description on Microsoft's side is usually too general to adapt its capabilities to the demand of the project.... Anybody can help me something?

Comment: Please share the code of your app, how you are importing files or modules

Comment: @VivekVaibhavShandilya I'm added now

Answer (score 0):

The NodeJS doesn't support ES module by default. You have to change `"module":"ESNext"` to `"module": "commonjs"` in your `tsconfig.json` at your `bot` folder.

If you want to use `ESNext` as your TS output module type. You should add `--experimental-modules` to your start command like `package.json` shows below. (ignored other option)

```json
{
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node --experimental-modules ./lib/index.js"
    }
}
```

You can test your project by running command like

```bash
cd /your_project_root/bot
npm install
npm run build
npm run start
```

The outcome of your changes will determine whether you see error output or the server starts.

Comment: You can also refer these teams app related samples: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/tab-device-permissions/nodejs

Comment: this is not working, I have still problem, I'm added now code for presenting how I import codes..

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft, could you take a look on update my question? I added code too.

Comment: Looks like your issue is related to Azure pipeline.

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft So what do I do next? Because I have to apply a solution with a bot. I don't know what to do and my hands are folded.

Comment: @LucasDomo If the error message `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` was not throw by your code in Azure. Please search for the log output in your Azure service. To enable that, follow the steps in [this link](https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/blob/dev/docs/fx-core/bot-help.md#2-is-there-anything-wrong-in-the-server-log-or-application-log). Examining the log output can help you find solutions. Or you can just update the log output to the question and help us to do more research about it.